# Ordering/arrangeing shape polygons by size, without a CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, print-composer, order, print-templates

I'd like to use QGIS to order/arrange polygons (or ideally, clipped rasters) from a map by area, to create an infographic diagram like this one I found online (sourced from https://www.visualcapitalist.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/true-size-of-countries-prev.jpg, Accessed 02/08/2022):

[image: Map of continents arranged by area, sourced from https://www.visualcapitalist.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/true-size-of-countries-1200px.jpg. Accessed 02/08/2022]

Is there a way to create a summary diagram like this using QGIS?

I know this can be done manually using vector graphic software like Adobe Illustrator. Still, the reason for wanting to automate this in QGIS is because I use QGIS to analyse microscopic images of minerals. Ideally, I want to be able to quickly pick out certain polygons (shapes of minerals) to visualise/analyse specific features in a rock. As far as I'm aware, no open-source software is available to do this.

Maybe it isn't possible to achieve this output using QGIS, but I thought I'd put this question to the community just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I've also being trying to find something similar, but without much luck so far.

As a stop-gap I wrote an R package called `morphogram` which takes a collection of polygons (as simple features from the `sf` package, see https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/) and arranges them into a grid.

It's not yet sophisticated enough to produce something as nice as the example you found (I expect there was a lot of manual graphical work if only to tweak things behind that one), but if you have any experience of playing with spatial data in R, it may help you on your way.

I welcome pull/merge requests.

See: https://tcwilkinson.github.io/morphogram/